WiFi and Nvidia driver failure on PC build
I assembled a desktop computer, and am having trouble with (1) GPU driver installation and (2) connecting to WiFi. I ask both questions here because I'm not sure if they're due to a common cause (incompatibility of hardware) or if they're independent issues. But I suspect this is a firmware issue, hence my posting the question under Ask Ubuntu.
Please guide me on how I can debug the issue and get the GPU/WiFi working for my PC. I'd be happy to iterate to get to the problem, and edit this post to better reflect the core issue and solution for future visits.
GPU
Issues
Ultimately I'd like to be able to detect GPU with nvidia-smi. Currently, my graphics seems to have more severe issues.

Turning off the computer often raises an error screen with the message "nvidia-modeset: Error: GPU:0: Error while waiting for GPU progres". When this occurs, I have to force quit my PC.
Turning on the PC often results in a black screen appearing after login. This happens about 2/3 of the times I boot my PC, while the other 1/3 times login goes through and I can access my computer.
Nvidia drivers were successfully installed once (or twice?). I checked that nvidia-smi printed the GPU. However nvidia-smi started failing after reboot and I can't get it to work now. As of now, nvidia-smi prints the message "Unable to determine the device handle for GPU0000:05:00.0".
It might be possible that the issue is caused by my power supply unit (PSU), which supplies 850W (Gold).

Problems / Status / Attempted Solutions
The attempts below may not be in chronological order and there may have been some problems mixed together.

My most recent nvidia driver installation was for version 560.35.03, checking with modinfo nvidia | grep version. This is from the ppa installation, and I've tried 550 as well as some lower versions before with the same issues.
The command dmesg | grep -i nvidia shows "module verification failed: signature and/or required key missing - tainting kernel."
I've tried installing the nvidia-drivers in many ways, including the ubuntu-drivers autoinstall and the manual apt install nvidia-driver-550 commands.
I've purged nvidia drivers with apt-get purge nvidia* to make sure that there are no conflicting versions.
I blacklisted nouveau by modifying blacklist-nouveau.conf to include blacklist nouveau and options nouveau modeset=0, then re-generating initramfs.
I've even tried the ppa to install drivers with add-apt-repository -r ppa:xor-edgers/ppa.

WiFi
I can't connect to my home wifi, but I can connect to my mobile hotspot. What's strange is that I was able to connect and use my home wifi once, before it started failing after a reboot.
Status/Attempts

I can connect to my phone Hotspot every time, but it's fairly slow.
nmcli dev wifi list shows my home wifi that I'm trying to connect to.
I checked for driver issues using lspci -k | grep -A 3 Network. It detects my MEDIATEK MT7922 chipset with kernel driver in use: mt7921e.
I've tried deleting and re-connecting with nmcli connection delete $NAME and ncmli dev wifi connect $NAME password $PASSWORD`.
Wifi power saving mode is switched from 3 to 2.
I've disconnected some other devices from the home wifi to make sure the problem is not because of too many connections.


Hardware and Software specs

OS: Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS
Kernel: 6.8.0-41-generic
CPU: AMD Ryzen 7 770x
Graphics: AMD Radeon Graphics (part of CPU?) and NVIDIA 4080
Memory: 1TB SSD
Power Supply Unit (PSU): 850W Gold
Motherboard: MSI MAG B650 Tomahawk WiFi


Check after a purge of all the nvidia packages -- some names don't start with nvidia, so "nvidia" might be necessary to really cleanup.  560 from graphics-drivers PPA should be fine for a 4080. Does lspci show the 4080? I haven't blacklisted nouveau in anything in /etc/modprobe.d, not doing that might prevent some black screens.

As the wifi worked once did you update the kernel on the first boot? If so try booting to the previous kernel (select from grub menu). Is the driver pre-built or a locally built one? Also add actual kernel(s) you are using ('uname -r'. (Append info. to question.) I did find the following link which might be of some help. https://superuser.com/questions/1843548/extremely-slow-wifi-between-ubuntu-24-04-lts-laptop-and-deco-m5-mesh-access-poin (driver mt7921e) At the very least it demos driver works with 24.04 even if a bit intermittently.

@david I haven't updated the kernel after my first boot. WiFi driver is pre-built. Kernel information is added to the question. I've already tried changing the wifi.conf to disable power saving but to no success.
I'm not sure how to understand the fact that my mobile hotspot works but home wifi doesn't? I suspect that this might hint at what might be the underlying issue.

@ubfan1 lspci does show the 4080. Could you explain what you mean by '"nvidia" might be necessary to really cleanup'?

Oops, the asterisks got converted.  Try putting an asterisk before and after the word nvidia.  Then check that there are no packages at all with nvidia in the name with dpkg -l | grep nvidia   Another thing to check is for motherboard firmware updates.

What does 'lsmod | grep 7921'  & 'modinfo mt7921e | grep -i version' & 'dkms status' report (append answer to question.) ...but home wifi doesn't?... Probably because the driver for this one is now not compatible with the kernel.
